# Im having a 'time limit exceeded' error in this code can anyone

Tags: ocaml, time-limiting

So the code is to calculate the cost of each colony, where the earth is the top one, like a tree,and the rules are the cost for the leafs is the cost they need to take to reach earth, and for the middle nods it depends they can go to the earth or to other leaf that needs to pass by them to reach the earth, the input is somelike like this [(1,2,5);(2,3,15)....], the 'a' is the first planet, the 'b' is the destination planet and 'c' is the cost that takes to make the travel between those two then with more inputs it creates a tree.

```ml
let p = read_int() (*Input com o numero de planetas*)
  (*let () = if p < 0 then failwith "Valor Incorreto" Verifica se o numero de planetas é pelo menos positivo*)

let m = read_int() (*Input com o numero de wormholes*)
  let () = if m < p-1 || m > p || m = p then failwith "Valor Incorreto" (*Verifica se o numero de wormholes e -1 c*)

let buracos = Array.make m (0, 0, 0) (*Cria o tuplo com os inputs*)

let conexoes m buracos = (*Le os inputs e coloca em tuplos*)
  for i = 0 to m - 1 do
     buracos.(i) <- Scanf.scanf  " %d %d %d" (fun a b c -> a, b, c)
  done

let colonias lburacos p =
    let x = List.filter (fun (a, _, _) -> a = p) lburacos
    in List.map (fun (_, b, c) -> (b, c)) x

let () = conexoes m buracos 

let lburacos = Array.to_list buracos

let resultados = Array.make p 0

let pais buracos p =
  let x = List.filter (fun (_, b, _) -> b = p) buracos
  in List.map (fun (a, _, c) -> (a, c)) x

let rec calc_raizes buracos p custo =
  let anteriores = pais buracos p in
    List.iter (fun (a, c) -> resultados.(a - 1) <- max resultados.(a - 1) (custo + c); calc_raizes buracos a (custo + c)) anteriores

let rec calc_folhas buracos p custo =
  let proximos = colonias buracos p in
    if proximos = [] then calc_raizes buracos p 0
    else List.iter (fun (a, b) -> resultados.(a - 1) <- custo + b; calc_folhas buracos a (custo + b)) proximos

let () = calc_folhas lburacos 1 0
let () = resultados.(0) <- Array.fold_left max 0 resultados 

let () = Array.iter (Printf.printf "%d\n") resultados
```

Comment: This is pretty complicated code, so it would help to be able to reproduce your problem. Also a lot depends on the linkages between planets being non-cyclic. You should show a specific input that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two hints:

- You recompute the neighborhood of a node many times, and you traverse the whole list of edges each time.You should compute the neighborhood of all vertices (aka the adjacency matrix) once and for all, and by traversing the list of edges once.
- You can compute the distance in one pass rather than two. In particular, `calc_raizes` is unnecessary and inefficient (each leaf revisits all of its ancestors).

Comment: My professor told me to make a vector and save the output from `pais` and instead of calling the function `pais` every time in `calc_raizes` i only call the vector with the outputs so it doesnt need to calculate everything each time.